# C# Interface Implementation relationship is just "Can-Do" Relationship?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

Today somebody told me that interface implementation in C# is just "Can-Do" relationship, not "Is-A" relationship. This conflicts with my long-time believing in LSP(Liskov Substitution Principle). I always think that all inheritance should means "Is-A" relationship.

So, If interface implementation is just a "Can-Do" relationship. What if there is a interface "IHuman" and "IEngineer", and one class "Programmer" inherits  from "IHuman" & "IEngineer"? Surely, a "Programmer" Is A "IHuman" and A "IEngineer".

If it is just "Can-Do" relationship, does it mean we cannot expect the "Programmer" instance behavior may be different between when treated as a IHuman and treated as IEngineer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my experience it doesn't really help that much to think of "is-a" and "can-do" relationships. You rapidly get into problems. It's an impedance mismatch between the real world and OO, basically. However much people actually talk about modeling the real world, you fundamentally need to understand what the relationships between types mean on the platform you're using.

Sometimes interfaces can be used as capabilities, and sometimes they can represent more of a normal "is-a" relationship. I wouldn't get too hung up about it - just make sure you understand what they can do and what they can't.

Comment: @Iain: Glad you're enjoying it. Do send me feedback when you've finished :)

Comment: What if you had an Abstract class with only abstract methods? How would that be different from an interface? I believe that there is no difference if only it is having method. then why microsoft has bring two things. Inheritance is having is-a releationship , What interface implementation ?

Comment: @Sudhir.net: I try to avoid talking about "is-a" relationships etc, as I've noted in the first sentence. An abstract class with only abstract methods is different from an interface in various details, such as a class only being able to derive from one other class, but being able to implement multiple interfaces. Classes can't declare generic variance, and are always value types (whereas interfaces can be implemented by value types as well). Abstract classes are more easily evolved, in that new (non-abstract) methods can be added without breaking existing subclasses.

Comment: @Jon, my abstract class is having only abtract for entire cycle of application.In the future there is no change in abtract class e.g no multiple interfaces, no fields, no non-abtract method. then how it is different my interface.? I want to understand implementation point of view ,what is the thought of microsoft guys behind this ?

Comment: @Sudhir.net: Well it's not like C# was the first language to have this split - it's very similar to abstract classes and interfaces in Java, for starters. The point isn't that your abstract class implements multiple interfaces, but if you had a second abstract class, a single class couldn't derive from both of your abstract classes - but it *could* implement multiple interfaces. Really, SO comments aren't the best place to go through the differences - I suggest you find a good introductory C# book.

Comment: @Jon.That's fine. But yesterday i had discussion with someone,i told all those things whatever you have mentioned above.But he told based on relationship there is difference between abstract and interface if abstract class have only abstract methof ,no multiple inheritance,no other things.

Comment: @Sudhir.net: That person is simply wrong. When you say "no multiple inheritance" that's not determined by the interface/abstract class, it's determined by the implementors/subclasses. Ask that person how they would write a struct deriving from your abstract class... Anyway, as I say, this really isn't an appropriate place to have that discussion. (You could look for questions more directly about "what is the difference between an abstract class and an interface.)

Comment: @Jon: i am taking this understanding from this discussion-  the reason behind this Micorsoft bring these two concepts.: Abstract is superclass,can also have non-abstract method,fields.Interface is having purpose of multiple inheritance. It's nothing to do with "is-a" and "can-do"

Comment: @Sudhir.net: Sorry, I've said multiple times that this isn't the place for this. I won't be commenting any more here.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to think of interfaces as a contract of behaviour. Interfaces such as IComparable and IEnumerable are classic examples.

In the example you gave, IHuman and IEngineer are not really behaviours.

Answer (score 4):

Found this question rather late but I wanted to chime in.

Interfaces in C# have an is-a relationship, but not is-an-object. Rather, is-an-implementation.

In other words, for class Foo that implements IBar, the following test:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo(); 
return myFoo is IBar;
```

literally returns true. You can also say,

```
IBar bar = myArrayList[3] as IBar;
Foo foo = bar as Foo;
```

Or, if a method requires an IBar, you can pass a Foo.

```
void DoSomething(IBar bar) {
}

static void Main() {
    Foo myFoo = new Foo();
    DoSomething(myFoo);
}
```

Obviously, an IBar has no implementation in itself, so the can-do relationship also applies.

```
interface IBar { void happy(); }
class Foo : IBar
{
    void happy()
    {
        Console.Write("OH MAN I AM SO HAPPY!");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IBar myBar = new Foo();
        myBar.happy();
    }
}
```

But, for that matter, the same is true of object inheritance; an object of class Foo that inherits class Bar has a can-do relationship as well as an is-a relationship, in the same way as the interface does. It's just that its implementation was pre-built for it.

The real question is, is-a-*what*, can-do-*what*? An inherited class object is-a-*[parent instance]* and can-do-*[parent's behavior]*, whereas an implementation of an interface is-an-*[interface implementation]* and therefore can-do-*[the interface behavior]*.

In most cases where programmatic is-a relationships are used such as those listed above, only the interface is evaluated, so both an inherited class and an implemented interface share the same is-a and can-do qualities.

HTH,
Jon

Answer (score 2):

The designers of the .NET framework use interfaces to designate a "has a" (or "can do") relationship, whereas "is a" is implemented using inheritance.

The rationale for this can be found in the [Choosing Between Classes and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013.aspx) section of the .NET Framework Developer's Guide:

> An interface defines the signatures for a set of members that implementers must provide. Interfaces cannot provide implementation details for the members.

So,  since your "Programmer" and "Engineer" example classes would most likely come with their own specific functionality, they would be more suitably implementated using inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's why most of the interface are capabilities and not names so you have

IComparable, ITestable, IEnumerable

and

Human, Animal, Dog, etc

Anyway, as it has been already mentioned you have to be pragmatic, I've got a general rule when I'm coding: **never let concepts, conventions or standard practices get on the way of getting the job done, better be pragmatic than academic.**

so if you're sure interfaces really fit better your design, go for it, don't worry about question such as this one.