# Is-A vs Has-A relationship

Tags: c#

Newbie Question which my course instructor has effectively confused the tar out of me.
Is-A relationship is when say a Dog is a animal.  Then you'd make Animal be the Base class with Dog as a derivative class.

But for our Class Project I have to make a class based on an interface.  With a separate class which only has one method to give a random number.  Seemingly they aren't really related, but I have to call the randomNumber Method from the main class.

His question during the instructions (which are terrible) say to figure out if this is an IS-A or HAS-A relationship.  Based on the facts I'd say this is a HAS-A relationship, but I have no idea how to reference the class, but to make a variable assigned to the class so I can use it.

Is there another way to Reference the class which I don't know?

```
Devices randomMeasure = new Devices();  //Random measurement Class
this.mostRecentMeasure = randomMeasure.GetMeasurement();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Interface Implementation relationship is just "Can-Do" Relationship?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/c-sharp-interface-implementation-relationship-is-just-can-do-relationship)

Comment: An interface is a CAN-DO relationship. It's not a IS-A nor a HAS-A

Comment: It's not clear to me how the first two paragraphs arrived at the question.  You can reference functionality on a class without an instance if that functionality is `static`, but that has nothing to do with inheritance or interface abstractions.

Comment: The Teachers instructions Literally ask us if it's an IS-A or HAS-A relationship.  HAS-A is a term I've never heard about throughout my textbook which is where my confusion came from.

Thank you I totally forgot about 'static'.

Comment: I like Jon Skeet's answer regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/c-sharp-interface-implementation-relationship-is-just-can-do-relationship

Comment: I think that if OP's instructor hasn't introduced the concept of 'CAN-DO', then this won't help OP very much. While technically correct, one can also argue that the IS-A relationship applies. Which is to say, if class `SomeClass` implements interface `ISomeInterface`, then `SomeClass` IS-A `ISomeInterface`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Interface is a Can-Do relationship. 
You can assign an instance of a class to any variable that is of the type of

1. the class itself or
2. one of the base classes of the class or
3. an interface that the class or one of its base classes implement.

In your example (case 3), this means:

```
IDevice randomMeasure = new Devices();
randomMeasure.GetMeasurement();
```

This concept is referred to as [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Thank you for the Can-Do definition.  I've learned about interfaces (briefly) already enough to complete the project at least.  Still don't understand the advantages of using them, but thanks.

Comment: Interfaces define the outer structure of the classes that implement them. A practical Advantage is that a class can implement lots of Interfaces whereas it can only have one base class. Important is that inheritance is a string Is-A-relationship. Can-Do is a weaker relationship that can also be used to share behavior among classes that otherwise are not related to one another.

Answer (score 9):

If your class inherits from the other class, it is an **"IS-A"** relationship.

If the class is passed to the other class in the constructor this is a **"HAS-A"** relationship.

e.g.

```cs
public interface IBar {}

public class Foo : IBar
{
    // IS-A IBar
}

public class Foo
{
    private IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    // HAS-A IBar
}
```

However, it's not obvious what it is your've asking.  In the second case, `Foo` **IS-A** `IBar` and **HAS-A** `Bar`.

Comment: Thank you for the HAS-A definition.  I needed that... honestly from my point of view there is no relationship naturally between the two.  Whomever wrote the instructions must have thought differently.  Imagine getting instructions for a project and never gives you the goal of the project.

Answer (score 3):

This is a IS-A relationship, the

To reference it, you should create an instance of the concrete class and assign it to the variable of the interface type:

```
interface IMeasureable 
{
    public int GetMeasurement();
}
class Device : IMeasureable 
{
    public int GetMeasurement() 
    {
        return .... 
    }
}
class App 
{
    public void Main() 
    {
         IMeasureable thing = new Device();
         int x = thing.GetMeasurement();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question ( although I am not sure why did you ask)
You may

1. Instantiate the class
2. Make it static
3. Keep the class object in a application variable / Cache / View State etc
4. Use extension method which will give you random number ( You dont have to use another class in that case)

Answer (score 2):

If we accept that Interfaces are CAN-DO relationships then the professor must be asking the relationship between the two concrete classes.  I'll call these classes `ClassBasedOnInterface` and `SeperateClass`.  Where `ClassBasedOnInterface` is aka "main class".  We also know the requirement is:

> I have to call the randomNumber Method from the main class.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Call();
}

//Requirement: I have to call the randomNumber Method from the main class.
public class ClassBasedOnInterface : IMyInterface
{
    SeperateClass hasASeperateClass = new SeperateClass();

    public void Call()
    {
        //Could be local variable.  
        //Or, the professor could be implying that ClassBasedOnInterface has a SeperateClass 
        //member that is used to make the call to GetRandomNumber().  
        //Or, GetRandomNumber() could be static.
        //var seperateClass = new SeperateClass();//I do not consider a private local variable a HAS-A relationship
        //seperateClass.GetRandomNumber();

        hasASeperateClass.GetRandomNumber();
    }
}

public class SeperateClass
{
    public void GetRandomNumber()
    {

    }
}
```

There are still many unanswered questions.  However, there is no reason to believe that `ClassBasedOnInterface` also derives from `SeperateClass`.  There is evidence to suggest that `SeperateClass` is a member of `ClassBasedOnInterface` because the requirement is that `ClassBasedOnInterface` must call `SeperateClass.GetRandomNumber()`.  In other words, there is no reason to believe an IS-A relationship exists.

For this reason I believe the answer is:

**`ClassBasedOnInterface` has a HAS-A relationship with `SeperateClass`**

Answer (score 2):

An interface describes something about a class, but doesn't necessarily define it.  As others have said, it's more of a Can-Do relationship.  Can you do something to/with this class, etc.

A Has-A relationship would be a class that utilizes other classes to represent something in a 0..* relationship.

```
// This interface doesn't really define what a class is, only
// that it can, in fact, have Cheeseburgers.
public interface ICanHasCheeseburgers
{
     List<Cheeseburger> Cheeseburgers { get; }
}

// This abstract class, defines what a derived class 'is'.
// If you are familiar with biology, imagine: kingdom, phylum, class, order, 
// genius, species.  It's different levels of abstraction for a 'thing'.
public abstract class Animal
{

}

// The cat class derives from the Animal class just as a Dog class might.
// This is a Is-A relationship; the Cat is an Animal.  It also implements 
// the ICanHasCheeseburgers interface which represents a Can-Do relationship.
public class Cat : Animal, ICanHasCheeseburgers
{
     // this property represents a Has-A relationship between our Cat
     // class and a Cheeseburger class.  The cat can have any number of
     // Cheeseburger objects.
     public List<Cheeseburger> Cheeseburgers { get; private set; }

     public Cat(RandomNumberGenerator generator) 
     {
          if (generator != null) 
          {
              var number = generator.GetRandom();
              var burgers = new List<Cheeseburger>();

              while(number > 0) {
                  burgers.add(new Cheeseburger());
                  number--;
              }

              Cheeseburgers = burgers;
          }
     }
}
```

Can-Do and Is-A relationships allow us to abstract logic.  Suppose we have any number of `Animals` and we want to know how many `Cheeseburgers` they have all together.  This would not be fun if we had to write a method for each animal and then try and add them together. But with an abstraction, we can write one method.

```
public static class Util
{
     public int GetTotalCheeseburgerCount(List<Animal> animals)
     {
          var total = 0;

          foreach(var animal in animals)
          {
               // not every animal can have cheeseburgers, so we 
               // can ignore this animal if it can't.
               var canHasCheeseburger = animal as ICanHasCheeseburger;
               if (canHasCheeseburger != null)
               {
                   if (canHasCheeseburger.Cheeseburgers != null)
                   {
                       total += canHasCheeseburger.Cheeseburgers.Count;
                   }
               }
          }

          return total;
      }
 }
```